# What purpose does overflow: hidden; serve?

Tags: css

I have a web page with a header area in the middle. Elements are then part of the header. Can someone explain what `overflow: hidden;` does here. I don't understand why I need it or what it does.

```
#hdr_mdl {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 980px;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 50px; 
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` prevents scrollbars from showing up, even when they're necessary.

Explanation of your CSS:

- `margin: 0 auto` horizontally aligns the element at the center
- `overflow:hidden` prevents scrollbars from appearing
- `width:980px` sets the width of the element to be `980px`.
- `z-index:10` causes the element to stay on top of elements without a defined `z-index`, *or- elements with a `z-index` below 10, *or* elements with a `z-index` of 10, but defined in before the current element
- `heigh:50px` - a height of `50px`.

Comment: `Overflow: hidden` also serves to actually *hide* the content that doesn't fit in the element's box. If height was not set, it would also serve to adjust the element's height so as to contain any floated children elements.

Answer (score 3):

When `overflow: hidden` is added to the container element, it hides its children that don’t fit in the container.
**Example:**

```css
.overflowhidden {
 background: green;
 width: 10rem;
 height: 10rem;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflowhidden">
 This container has the style overflow:hidden. Text that does not fit becomes hidden. This is a very long sentence of text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text even more text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text this is the end of the sentence.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content in #hdrPmdl was to spill over 50px it will not allow the browser to insert scrollbars into the DIV. If the DIV doesnt contain dynamic content and the size will always remain static then it is probably not needed as the content will no be > 50px

Answer (score 0):

`overflow` specifies what a browser should do, when content is **bigger** than block dimensions. `overflow:hidden` means 'hide it and preserve initial block dimensions'.

Answer (score 0):

if you use overflow hidden for a particular content than the overflow is clipped for this content, and the rest of the content will be invisible. for clear the matter visit w3school
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score -2):

Explanation of the `overflow` property: [CSS overflow Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Interactive example of the `overflow` property: [Play it](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=hidden)