# How to adjust the div inside the div

Tags: html, css

I want to align the div inside anathor div but unable to move the div ( class name = circleIcon) vertically along the div as i tried to adjust it through the margin-top, it is moving the parent div "div2Main". I want to align the circleIcon div 6px below the parent Div "div2Main.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Screen1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Screen1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header1Main">
<div id="header1">Composite Timeline</div>
<div id="header2"><img src="images/drop-down-arrow.png"></img></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div2Main">
   <div class="circleIcon"> </div>

</div>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
#header1Main
{

}
#header1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 36px;   
    background-color:green;
    left: 0;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
    float: left;
}

#header2 
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20%;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    background-color:blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.div2Main
{   clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    display:block;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-left:12px;
    height:64px;
}
.clear { clear:both; height: 12px; }

.circleIcon {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px; 
    background-color:#ffb400;
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/678n2837/1/

Comment: did you tried using relative position on .circleIcon?

Comment: Yes I tried but of no use. 

As you can see margin-left is working fine but margin-top is giving  me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

try this css.Check this fiddle link [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/678n2837/9/)

```
.circleIcon {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px; 
    background-color:#ffb400;
    margin-left: 12px;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css (just changes):

```
.div2Main
{
    position: relative;
}

.circleIcon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-right: -14px;
}
```

it position `.circleIcon` absolute inside parent `.div2Main`. it works even if `.div2Main` change its width or height.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/678n2837/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Now define to this

```
.div2Main{
 overflow:hidden;
}

.circleIcon {
  margin-top:10px; // define here as per need
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/678n2837/5/)**

**The CSS Overflow Property**

There are four values for the overflow property: visible (default), hidden, scroll, and auto. There are also sister properties overflow-y and overflow-x, which enjoy less widespread adoption.

**[more info](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)**

**[What purpose does overflow: hidden; serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627625/what-purpose-does-overflow-hidden-serve/7627639#7627639)**

Comment: can you please explain . what does this overflow:hidden do?